# Aligning the image in the Linear Layout

Tags: android

[image]

Below is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/header"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/viewpager_header_height"
                android:src="@drawable/bgimage"
                />

            <com.interbind.praveeng.recipeapp.widget.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tabs_height"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I want the image to fill the full width of Linearlayout.

Comment: what width you have set for parent of linear layout

Comment: add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to `ImageView`  it fill image with height and width

Comment: match parent width I have set for Linear layout parent.

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" to ImageView is working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add scaleType.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/viewpager_header_height"
    android:src="@drawable/bgimage"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<ImageView      
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/viewpager_header_height"
     android:src="@drawable/bgimage"/>
```

good luck